# Look for an element in a 2d Array using contains

Tags: java

I have a 2D array and want to use contains method to check if myChar is part of myArray[i][0]

```
public static final String[][] myArray = {
        {"NM1", "DESC1"},
        {"NM2", "DESC2"},
        {"NM3", "DESC3"},
        {"NM4", "DESC4"},
        {"NM5", "DESC5"}
    }

Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(mychar);
```

However this is failing for me. When i make it as 1D array like:

```
public static final String[][] myArrayNm = {
    "NM1",
    "NM2",
    "NM3",
    "NM4",
    "NM5"
}

Arrays.asList(myArrayNm).contains(mychar);
```

is working for me. Is there a way i can do the value check using 2D array (loop will be the last option)

Comment: contains work with 1-D arrays not multi-dimenstional arrays. And also what @codebox said.

Comment: I think you should use a loop.

Comment: How come myArrayNm.contains works and since when and what are you going to get output if ever api exists that you could input it to Arrays.asList? Do you know that contains internally uses loop?

Comment: I know contains internally uses loop. :) I just want my code to look cleaner. Is there a way to search for an element in a 2D array ? Something like contains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public static final String[][] myArray = {
        {"NM1", "DESC1"},
        {"NM2", "DESC2"},
        {"NM3", "DESC3"},
        {"NM4", "DESC4"},
        {"NM5", "DESC5"}
    }

List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(myArray);
for(String[] arr: list){
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).contains("myString"));
}
```

Not realy performant, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you turn your 2D array into a list you are creating a list where the elements are arrays, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String[] array : myArray) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }
System.out.println(list.contains(mychar));
```